# Have logstash JDBC input `last_run_metadata_path` on an external source?

Tags: logstash, logstash-jdbc

We want to run logstash in an ECS environment where the instances have transient lives. They might be long lived, but they aren't permanent. Thus, having logstash store the `sql_last_value` in the `last_run_metadata_path` doesn't work if the instance is removed and then brought up again. That state gets lost.

Is there a way to have that value pulled from a S3 path? Or via a DB query? I'm just looking somewhere persistent that won't vanish when the instance gets deleted and brought up again.

```
last_run_metadata_path => "/home/ckessel/.logstash_source_a"  <-- need that to be S3 or some such
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file input just [reads](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-jdbc/blob/878a73eb67b68366fac74fcc65e9cadd6cf44766/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/jdbc/value_tracking.rb#L118) the saved value from a file. So the location can be anything that the Ruby IO::read function can read. That does not include s3 or a database. It needs to be a filesystem, but it can be network mounted.